# Efficently multiply a matrix with itself after offsetting it by one in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to write a function that takes a matrix A, then offsets it by one, and does element wise matrix multiplication on the shared area. Perhaps an example will help. Suppose I have the matrix:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

What i'd like returned is:
    (1*2) + (4*5) + (7*8) = 78

The following code does it, but inefficently:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

Height = A.shape[0]
Width = A.shape[1]

Sum1 = 0
for y in range(0, Height):    
        for x in range(0,Width-2):
            Sum1 = Sum1 + \
                A.item(y,x)*A.item(y,x+1)
            print("%d * %d"%( A.item(y,x),A.item(y,x+1)))

print(Sum1)
```

With output:

```
1 * 2
4 * 5
7 * 8
78
```

Here is my attempt to write the code more efficently with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

print(np.sum(np.multiply(A[:,0:-1], A[:,1:])))
```

Unfortunately, this time I get 186. I am at a loss where did I go wrong. i'd love someone to either correcty me or offer another way to implement this.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to provide a more precise description of your requirements. Why doesn't your operation do anything with the last column of `A`? How is this "element wise matrix multiplication on the shared area"?

Comment: `np.dot(A[:,0], A[:,1])` returns `78`.

Comment: IIUC you need to use the summation along the first axis : `np.sum(np.multiply(A[:,0:-1], A[:,1:]),axis=0)`. With the `default np.sum()`, its's summing up everything into one scalar.

Answer (score 0):

In this 3 column case, you are just multiplying the 1st 2 columns, and taking the sum:

```
A[:,:2].prod(1).sum()
Out[36]: 78
```

Same as  `(A[:,0]*A[:,1]).sum()`

Now just how does that generalize to more columns?

In your original loop, you can cut out the row iteration by taking the sum of this list:

```
[A[:,x]*A[:,x+1] for x in range(0,A.shape[1]-2)]
Out[40]: [array([ 2, 20, 56])]
```

Your description talks about multiplying the shared area; what direction are you doing the offset?  From the calculation it looks like the offset is negative.

```
A[:,:-1]
Out[47]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

If that is the offset logic, than I could rewrite my calculation as

```
A[:,:-1].prod(1).sum()
```

which should work for many more columns.

===================

Your 2nd try:

```
In [3]: [A[:,:-1],A[:,1:]]
Out[3]: 
[array([[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]]), 
 array([[2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [8, 9]])]    

In [6]: A[:,:-1]*A[:,1:]
Out[6]: 
array([[ 2,  6],
       [20, 30],
       [56, 72]])

In [7]: _.sum()
Out[7]: 186
```

In other words instead of 1*2, you are calculating [1,2]*[2*3]=[2,6].  Nothing wrong with that, if that's you you really intend.  The key is being clear about 'offset' and 'overlap'.